# bootstrap table responsive head fixed body scrollable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 to make my site responsive and I have a table with a div that is "table-responsive". I want a table that allows me to scroll vertically when the screen is small but it also needs to scroll horizontally because their are over 50 items in the table. How can I get the table to be scrollable and responsive?

I am trying this css but the table grows and is not scrolling horizontally...

```
application.css.scss

  //table becomes responsive with scrollbar
  .table-responsive {
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px !important;
   overflow: auto;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
   -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
   border: 1px solid #DDD;
  }
```

The above css works but the head needs to be fixed above the scrolling body.

```
html

<div class= "container">
 <div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-colored table-hover table-bordered">
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="20%">Applicant's Name</th>
      <th width="20%">Applicant's Email</th>
      <th width="20%">Date Requested </th>
      <th width="40%">Report View/Download</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
        <% current_manager.reportapprovals.each do |ra| %>
          <% if ra.report.present? %>
              <tr>
                <td width="20%"><%= ra.tenant_last_name.truncate(17) %></td>
                <td width="20%"><%= ra.tenant_email.truncate(17) %></td>
                <td width="20%"><%= ra.date_approved %></td>
              </tr>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
  </tbody>
</div>
</table>
```

Comment: please post your HTML code as well.

Comment: try this link  https://jsfiddle.net/ho9mo49r/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can change CSS like this to get vertical and horizontal scroll

```
.table-responsive {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   overflow-x: auto;
   overflow-y: auto;
   display: block;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
   -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
   border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xx8j9tLt/

**Update**

With fixed header

CSS

```
.container {
  width:400px;
  height: 100px;
}
.table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: block;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    position: relative;
}

table thead {
   position: fixed;
   width: auto;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

JS (with jquery)

```
function setThead() {
    var tableWidth = $('.table-responsive').width();
  $('.table-responsive thead').css('width',tableWidth);
};
setThead();
window.onresize = setThead;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xx8j9tLt/1/

Comment: This doesn't have the fixed header on scroll